# spacing and width table css

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I need help on this. I'm not very good with CSS/layout or UI design. I'm just figuring it out how. This one can't figure it out, why it's doing what it's doing on these tables:

[image]

In the red box, my problem is the other numbers and questions are align, but when it comes to number 4,it stretches.

Below is my html code:

```
       <asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div id="divQuestionnaires" runat="server" class="SiteWide_PageContent_Centered">
    <table ID="tblQuestionnaires1" runat="server">
        <tr >
            <th Style="padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold;">
                <label ID="lbl1" 
                    runat="server"                      
                    text="1."/>
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <label ID="lblQuestion1"
                    runat="server"                    
                    text="Question1" />
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;" >
                <TextBox ID ="txtAnswer1" runat="server"  CssClass="width8em" width="80pt"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <th Style="padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold;">
                <label ID="lbl2" 
                    runat="server"
        text="2."/>
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <label ID="lblQuestionnaire2"
                    runat="server"                       
                    text="Question2" />
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;" >
               <RadioButtonList ID="rblQ2YesNo" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                   <asp:ListItem Value=1 Text="[Yes]"/>
                   <asp:ListItem Value=2 Text="[No]"/>
               </RadioButtonList>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th Style="padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold;">
                <label ID="lbl2a" 
                    runat="server"                        
                    text="2a."/>
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <label ID="lblQuestionnaire2a"
                    runat="server"                       
                    text="Question2a" />
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;" >
                <TextBox ID ="txtAnswer2a" runat="server"  CssClass="width8em" width="80pt"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
         <tr >
            <th Style="padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold;">
                <label ID="lbl3" 
                    runat="server"                        
                    text="3."/>
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <label ID="lblQuestionnaire3"
                    runat="server"                       
                    text="Question3" />
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;" >
               <RadioButtonList ID="rblQ3YesNo" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                   <asp:ListItem Value=1 Text="[Yes]"/>
                   <asp:ListItem Value=2 Text="[No]"/>
               </RadioButtonList>
            </th>
        </tr>
         <tr >
            <th Style="padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold;">
                <label ID="lbl3a" 
                    runat="server"                        
                    text="3a."/>
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:10px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <label ID="lblQuestionnaire3a"
                    runat="server"                       
                    text="Question3a" />
            </th>
        </tr>           
    </table>
</div>
 <div id="divQuestionnaires2" runat="server" class="SiteWide_PageContent_Centered">
    <table runat="server" ID="tblQuestionnaires2" style="padding-top:40px;table-layout:fixed">
       <tr >
            <th Style="padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold;">
                <label ID="DNR_Label1" 
                    text="4."/>
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <label ID="lblQuestion4"
                    runat="server"                       
                   text="Question4" />
            </th> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;" >
                <CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkLstAnswer4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="[Increased]" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="[Decreased]" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="[Remained the same]" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="[Don't know]" />
                </CheckBoxList>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div  id="divChartForQ3a" runat="server" class="SiteWide_PageContent_Centered">
    <table runat="server" ID="tblWMZ" style="border-collapse:collapse;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:break-word;font-size:12px;">
        <tr BorderWidth="1">
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                <label runat="server" ID="lblHeadeWMZhunt"
                               text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderDaysHuntedBow"
                                text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderDaysHuntedGun"
                                text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderNoDeerSeen"
                                text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                   <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderNoCoyotesSeen"
                                text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderNoBearsSeen"
                               text=""/>                                         
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderNoMooseBullsSeen"
                               text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                 <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderNoMooseCowsSeen"
                               text=""/>                    
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderNoMooseCalvesSeen"
                               text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderUnknown"
                               text=""/>
            </th>                  
        </tr>
            <tr BorderWidth="1">
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtWMZhunt" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtDaysHuntedBow" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtDaysHuntedGun" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtNoDeerSeen" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtNoCoyotesSeen" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtNoBearsSeen" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtNoMooseBullsSeen" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th> 
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtNoMooseCowsSeen" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtNoMooseCalvesSeen" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtUnknown" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

</asp:Content>

This is the CSS for Column #4:

[image]

This is the CSS for Column Question#4:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which contains the resulting HTML/CSS in the browser and which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Hi bro`

Check the see that it is fixed now ?

You have wrongly placed question 4 outside the table

I put code 99 to 110 () in code line 82 and wrote ()

```html
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div id="divQuestionnaires" runat="server" class="SiteWide_PageContent_Centered">
    <table ID="tblQuestionnaires1" runat="server">
        <tr >
            <th Style="padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold;">
                <label ID="lbl1" 
                    runat="server"                      
                    text="1."/>
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <label ID="lblQuestion1"
                    runat="server"                    
                    text="Question1" />
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;" >
                <TextBox ID ="txtAnswer1" runat="server"  CssClass="width8em" width="80pt"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <th Style="padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold;">
                <label ID="lbl2" 
                    runat="server"
        text="2."/>
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <label ID="lblQuestionnaire2"
                    runat="server"                       
                    text="Question2" />
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;" >
               <RadioButtonList ID="rblQ2YesNo" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                   <asp:ListItem Value=1 Text="[Yes]"/>
                   <asp:ListItem Value=2 Text="[No]"/>
               </RadioButtonList>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th Style="padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold;">
                <label ID="lbl2a" 
                    runat="server"                        
                    text="2a."/>
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <label ID="lblQuestionnaire2a"
                    runat="server"                       
                    text="Question2a" />
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;" >
                <TextBox ID ="txtAnswer2a" runat="server"  CssClass="width8em" width="80pt"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
         <tr >
            <th Style="padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold;">
                <label ID="lbl3" 
                    runat="server"                        
                    text="3."/>
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <label ID="lblQuestionnaire3"
                    runat="server"                       
                    text="Question3" />
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;" >
               <RadioButtonList ID="rblQ3YesNo" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                   <asp:ListItem Value=1 Text="[Yes]"/>
                   <asp:ListItem Value=2 Text="[No]"/>
               </RadioButtonList>
            </th>
        </tr>
         <tr >
            <th Style="padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold;">
                <label ID="lbl3a" 
                    runat="server"                        
                    text="3a."/>
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:10px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <label ID="lblQuestionnaire3a"
                    runat="server"                       
                    text="Question3a" />
            </th>
        </tr>     
        <!-- Next : -->  
        <tr >
            <th Style="padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold;">
                <label ID="DNR_Label1" 
                    text="4."/>
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <label ID="lblQuestion4"
                    runat="server"                       
                   text="Question4" />
            </th> 
        </tr> 
     
    </table>
</div>
 <div id="divQuestionnaires2" runat="server" class="SiteWide_PageContent_Centered">
    <table runat="server" ID="tblQuestionnaires2" style="padding-top:40px;table-layout:fixed">
       <!-- Before : 
         <tr >
            <th Style="padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold;">
                <label ID="DNR_Label1" 
                    text="4."/>
            </th>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <label ID="lblQuestion4"
                    runat="server"                       
                   text="Question4" />
            </th> 
        </tr> -->
        <tr>
            <th Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;" >
                <CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkLstAnswer4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="[Increased]" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="[Decreased]" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="[Remained the same]" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="[Don't know]" />
                </CheckBoxList>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div  id="divChartForQ3a" runat="server" class="SiteWide_PageContent_Centered">
    <table runat="server" ID="tblWMZ" style="border-collapse:collapse;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:break-word;font-size:12px;">
        <tr BorderWidth="1">
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                <label runat="server" ID="lblHeadeWMZhunt"
                               text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderDaysHuntedBow"
                                text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderDaysHuntedGun"
                                text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderNoDeerSeen"
                                text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                   <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderNoCoyotesSeen"
                                text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderNoBearsSeen"
                               text=""/>                                         
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderNoMooseBullsSeen"
                               text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                 <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderNoMooseCowsSeen"
                               text=""/>                    
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderNoMooseCalvesSeen"
                               text=""/>
            </th> 
            <th BorderWidth="1" style="word-wrap:break-word;text-align:center;width:10%">
                  <label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderUnknown"
                               text=""/>
            </th>                  
        </tr>
            <tr BorderWidth="1">
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtWMZhunt" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtDaysHuntedBow" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtDaysHuntedGun" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtNoDeerSeen" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtNoCoyotesSeen" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtNoBearsSeen" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtNoMooseBullsSeen" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th> 
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtNoMooseCowsSeen" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtNoMooseCalvesSeen" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
                <th BorderWidth="1" CssClass="chartColumn">
                    <TextBox ID="txtUnknown" runat="server" CssClass="chartBox"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).